# Unity Navmesh Agent behavoiur on terrain

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a terrain (with some mountains, trees rivers etc.) and I want my agent to run smoothly on the whole terrain following the player (I mean drop from mountains and climb them to certain angle(e.g. jumping))

Agent is not "climbing"/dropping form mountains

One issue is that my agents cannot jump. I think I'm missing some settings. Here are my settings for navigation:

[image]

and settings for agent:

[image]

Also places like this are really buggy:
[image]

Agents are stuck near the red circle and trying to go in the direction of red arrow (but cannot proceed) I don't understand why they are stuck in this location and how I can check what's going wrong. (They can move like the purple arrow shows)

Comment: Could it be an issue with one of your scripts? If you don't mind sharing your code, I can try to check it out.

Comment: I was using default Unity Navmesh agents and models from standard assets. I tested it on test scene so it's unlikely that it's caused by my scripts. The issue is gone as I tested in 2018.3.

Answer (score -1):

If you want your NavMeshAgents to jump/climb, you'll need to generate [OffMesh Links](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-OffMeshLink.html).
You can do this [manually](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-CreateOffMeshLink.html), or you can tell Unity to [generate them automatically](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-BuildingOffMeshLinksAutomatically.html) when baking your NavMesh.

To prevent them from getting stuck near mountains and other obstacles, bump up the radius value in the Obstacle Avoidance settings (inside the NavMeshAgent component).